# Can't choose a country as a location of test

Tags: support, jobs

While updating my careers profile I've noticed that I can't enter country names anymore as locations where I'm willing to relocate to. The problem is that if I'm willing to relocate o a different country, I might not care about the city...

The error I'm receiving when I enter a country name, e.g. Denmark:

> [image]

And quoting the message itself:

> Sorry, we need a more specific location than 'Denmark'. Try again?

If I enter Luxembourg, the entry gets corrected to "Luxembourg City, Luxembourg" when I click outside of the textbox, but this is not what I actually meant.

I don't know how to specify that I would be willing to work anywhere in a country or even a continent.

Comment: We're looking into it, will get back later today

Answer (score 3):

Uh, a "minimal precision" parameter was not passed from the UI to the server, causing the "We need a more specific location" error.

It's now fixed, you can set a country as a relocation choice. Also, *Luxembourg* doesn't autocomplete to "*Luxembourg City, Luxembourg*" anymore.

As one would expect, employers searching for candidates in *New York* will find the developers who are willing to relocate to "*United States*" (for example). However, employers cannot find candidates who have set their profile as private or have blocked the search engine (see My Profile > privacy settings.)

Thanks for your report!